# Extract Gentrated item in Drafting

Tags: vba, selection, catia

Extract item of generated item in CAT Drawing for lines I am tiring
Drafting Generated Item selection
I am using this but not able extract it
help me out

TRY TO EXTRACT GENTRATEDITEM(Lines) IN Drawingsheet as per view

Comment: Can you clarify your question what you want to achieve? What have you tried so far?

Comment: I need to extract the generated item in Drawing view using search command.

Comment: `Selection.clear`
`selection.Search Drafting.Gentarted item,sel `
` Set temp = selection.Item(1).value`
its is not able extracted the Generated item

Comment: Generative elements (e.g. projected geometry from 3d) are not accessible via a macro.

Comment: any way to get those geometry through macro